# How to create a submodule in Azure Devops?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, git-submodules

I'm trying to add a submodule to Azure Devops.

I have created two Repo's and i'd like one to be a submodule of the other. Is this the way to go? Or do you just create a folder in the main Repo which adds the submodule? Is it possible with just the azure set up wizards?

I have only found how to checkout a submodule with the main Repo and literally nothing on how to actually create the submodule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use git command to create submodule. Here are the detailed steps:

1. Go to the local main repository. If your repository does not exist locally, please clone it. In your repository, click "Clone" to get clone URL. Copy it. Then, create a new folder locally and run the following command in the directory:

   ```
   git init
   git clone {clone URL}
   ```
2. Run the command:

   ```
   git submodule add {repository url}
   ```

   resository url: The url of your Azure DevOps repository: `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository}`

   Then you will find a `.gitmodules` file automatically generated. You can open it to check the submodule name and url.
3. Run the following command to add, commit and push the changes to Azure DevOps:

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m "commit message"
   git push origin {branch name}
   ```